# Sort a 2d array by its name column but ignoring the names' prefixes

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, custom-sort

I want to sort an array of rows by the `name` column value, but critically I want to sort while ignoring the users' prefixes.

Sample array:

```
$ad_users = [
    ["name" => "Mr San", "department" => "five"],
    ["name" => "Mr VSan", "department" => "six"],
    ["name" => "Mr QSan", "department" => "four"],
    ["name" => "Sr ASan", "department" => "two"],
    ["name" => "Dr ASan", "department" => "one"],
    ["name" => "Dr FSan", "department" => "three"]
];
```

Desired result:

```
[
    ["name" => "Dr ASan", "department" => "one"],
    ["name" => "Sr ASan", "department" => "two"],
    ["name" => "Dr FSan", "department" => "three"],
    ["name" => "Mr QSan", "department" => "four"],
    ["name" => "Mr San", "department" => "five"],
    ["name" => "Mr VSan", "department" => "six"]
]
```

My current code:

```
for ($x = 0; $x < count($ad_users); $x++) {
    $ad_users[$x]['name']= ucwords($ad_users[$x]['name']);
    $end = (explode(',', $ad_users[$x]['name']));
    $lastname = array_pop($end);
    sort($end);
    $firstname = implode(" ", $end);
    $ad_users[$x]['name']=$lastname." ".$firstname;
}
sort($ad_users);
for ($x = 0; $x < count($ad_users); $x++) {
    echo $ad_users[$x]['name']."\n";
}
```

Comment: You don't have `,` in your `name` values.

Comment: `$end = (explode(',', $ad_users[$x]['name']));`

No `','` but `'.'` ?

Comment: @BenjaminPoignant I have originally names are like this Abeer Aldoghaither, Dr

Comment: Are you loading these values from DB? if it so, why don't you apply sorting in the Query?

Comment: If you have DB development permissions, you should also split `name` into `title`, `lastname`, `firstnames`

Comment: @Thamilan No not from DB. Actually from Active Directory

Comment: can you show here your desired output, i think which you have shown so far is output from code used above , right ?

Comment: @u_mulder Yes I have. Originally names are like this Abeer Aldoghaither, Dr :)

Comment: @BrijalSavaliya List of: (Prefix. First name Last name) ordered alphabetically by first name :)

Comment: is it true ? for e.g.-  "Dr ASan" , "Sr ASan", "Dr FSan", "Mr QSan", "Mr San", "Mr VSan"

Comment: @AsmaaAlharbi , above order is right ?

Comment: @BrijalSavaliya No it should be "Dr ASan" , "Sr ASan", "Dr FSan", "Mr San", "Mr QSan", "Mr VSan" Regardless of Dr. Mr. Ms. first letters

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111724/discussion-between-brijal-savaliya-and-asmaa-alharbi).

Comment: As per alphabetically order "PQRS" , so why "Mr San", "Mr QSan", it should be "Mr QSan" then "Mr San" @AsmaaAlharbi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make it clear in your comment that you originally have the name as `firstname lastname, title`, so you just need to sort first, *then* move the title to the front:

```
<?php
sort($ad_users);

// I've copied this section as-is, it looks like it could be improved
// but I can't be sure I'm making the correct improvements without seeing
// the original data
for ($x = 0; $x < count($ad_users); $x++) {
    $ad_users[$x]['name']= ucwords($ad_users[$x]['name']);
    $end = (explode(',', $ad_users[$x]['name']));
    $lastname = array_pop($end);
    sort($end);
    $firstname = implode(" ", $end);
    $ad_users[$x]['name']=$lastname." ".$firstname;
}

for ($x = 0; $x < count($ad_users); $x++) {
    echo $ad_users[$x]['name']."\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
        uasort($array, function($a, $b) {
            $needles = ['Dr.', 'Ms.', ];
            $a = trim(str_replace($needles,'', $a['name']));
            $b = trim(str_replace($needles,'', $b['name']));
            if ($a == $b) {
                return 0;
            }
            return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
        });
```

Comment: both code has similar output , your answer and code used by @Asmaa Alharbi

Comment: True, my `str_replace` was incorrect because I didn't take notice `$a` and `$b` are arrays. Changed it to the `name` part of the array, should work fine now

Comment: I actually couldn't understand your solution nor how to use it

Comment: just replace `$array` with your array, `$ad_users` and then output the name like you did

Comment: just replace $array with your array, $ad_users and use print_r($ad_users); after that code

Comment: I got error at your Second line although I fix it to be : $needles = ['Dr.','Ms.','Mr' ]; Why is that ?

Comment: You need to populate the `needles` with all possible salutations, that is correct.

Comment: @DarkBee Sir I keep getting error at Second Line even although I change it to $needles = ['Dr.','Ms.','Mr' ]; What is wrong in that ??

Comment: You are using an older version of PHP : use this `$needles = array('Dr.','Ms.','Mr',);`

Answer (score 0):

You should prepare your data (Remove all Dr., Ms., etc) and then sort cleaned names only.

Comment: Yes, you can. You can do sort on cleaned name value copies, and display names with prefixes.

Comment: How then I would now their prefixes, I have 521 employee :)

Comment: There is limited number of possible prefixes (less then ten). First find all of them, then make copy of name lets call it name_sort, clean it from all possible prexies, and then do sort by it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Do not count() a constant array in a for loop!
You explode() with a non-existent delimiter, so the resulting array has exactly one element which you remove with array_pop(). Then you sort() and implode() an empty array.
So you get a random (in this case unchanged) result.

Please check http://php.net/usort

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code as

```
<?php
function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
     $prefix = ['Mr.', 'Ms.','Dr.'];
     $a = trim(str_replace($prefix,"", $a['name']));
     $b = trim(str_replace($prefix,"", $b['name']));

    return $a > $b;
}

$myArray = array(
      array("name"=>"Dr.    bbb"),
      array("name"=>"Mr. aaa"),
      array("name"=>"Ms.  ccc")
);

$abc = usort($myArray, 'sortByOrder');
print_r($myArray);
?>
```

Check here : https://eval.in/569467

Output would be :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Mr. aaa
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Dr.    bbb
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Ms.  ccc
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

`usort()` has a more expensive time complexity and will require double the function calls within each iteration.  Instead, I recommend using `array_multisort()` and preparing a sorting array with minimal function calls.

Isolate the `name` column values, then trim the prefix off of every value, then compare those strings.  After that, you can effectively sort on the prefixes by sorting on the whole rows.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Gg6E7))

```
array_multisort(
    preg_replace('/^[^ ]+ /', '', array_column($data, 'name')),
    $data
);
```